# Riemann Sum $\epsilon$ Criterion

Tags: real-analysis

[image]
[image]

In iii) I do not understand why the solution lets $\Delta_\epsilon$ be $\Delta_2$ when $\epsilon\geq 8$ i.e $>2$

Comment: $\Delta_\epsilon$ itself does not work if $\epsilon\ge 8$, hence a replacement partition must be picked. However, even the trivial partitoin gives a sum $=2<\epsilon$ and would be fine. The author picking $\Delta_2$ is probably because they prefer $1$ as value.

Comment: Bu the question asks to find a partition, not two different ones?

Comment: The question ask for "a partition", but that does not mean that there is only one partition that exists. It means you only have to find at least one! In all situations like this there are many (infinitely) many partitions that do the job. To find one, you can choose any $\Delta_x$ for $x<8$ and it will work. As Hagen says above, the choice $x=2$ is just the authors preference...just as choosing $\epsilon/8$ in the definition of $\Delta_\epsilon$ when $\epsilon/11.2$ or $\epsilon/7.39$ would be just as good.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, it's confusing you that part (iii) says "find **a** partition" and then in the solution they're using **two** different partitions. The key here is that part (iii) of the question says "Given an $\epsilon > 0$, find a partition..." which means that if someone hands you an $\epsilon > 0$, the partition you choose can depend on the $\epsilon$ you are given. The partitions we use for two different values of $\epsilon$ can be completely different and in many problems of this type they will be.

The author here splits the problem into two cases: $\epsilon < 8$ and $\epsilon \geq 8$. If we are given any $\epsilon < 8$, we know how to find a partition that does what we want using $\Delta_{\epsilon}$ (which is a function of $\epsilon$). If $\epsilon \geq 8$, then we don't even need the partition to depend on $\epsilon$ because we can just use $\Delta_2$ as that happens to work in all cases. We don't need the partition to depend on $\epsilon$ for values of $\epsilon \geq 8$ because $\Delta_2$ because $S(f, \Delta_2) = 1$ and we certainly have $1 \leq 8 \leq \epsilon$ for this range of $\epsilon$ values.

Answer (score 1):

It is not that there are two different partitions, but that apparently there are two rules to generate a partition depending on whether $\epsilon<8$ or not. The exercise is asking you to construct *a partition for each* $\epsilon>0$, which means that you need to construct a lot of partitions if you imagine that $\epsilon$ is varying.